# Select similar items of different lists using using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

In an asp.net mvc application, I am trying to perform a selection based on what user selects from product specifications.
Imagine a user selected these parameters as a selection:

```
manufacturer: [apple, sony, samsung]
ram: [8, 128, 256]
size: [12, 13.5]
```

based on that, lets say the selection resulted in lists of product Ids.

```
list1={10,12,18,100}
list2={10,18,20,21,100,102}
list3={1,2,9,10,12,18,100}
```

the result should be common Ids:

```
result={10,18,100}
```

Since there might be more than 3 lists, is there a Linq command for any number of lists?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation first?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Intersect` method provided by .NET. Here's the [documentation about the usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

Use intersect to get similar item from Two Lists.

```
List<string> Fruits = new List<string>();
        Fruits.Add("Apple");
        Fruits.Add("Mango");
        Fruits.Add("Grapes");
        Fruits.Add("Banana");
        Fruits.Add("Orange");
        Fruits.Add("Sweet Potato");

        List<string> Vegetables = new List<string>();
        Vegetables.Add("Tomato");
        Vegetables.Add("Potato");
        Vegetables.Add("Onion");
        Vegetables.Add("Apple");
        Vegetables.Add("Orange");
        Vegetables.Add("Banana");

        var Data = Fruits.Intersect(Vegetables).ToList();
        foreach(var d in Data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
```

Output:-
Apple
Banana
Orange